# dynamic memory deallocation error in OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, dynamic

I am wondering if OpenCV Mat default constructor already allocates the memory? as indicated in doc

```
>     These are various constructors that form a matrix. As noted in the Automatic Allocation of the Output Data, often the default constructor
> is enough, and the proper matrix will be allocated by an OpenCV
> function.
```

Does this mean that the deallocation happening at the end of my program is proper. Is that correct?

Actually, I am having a (core dump) error at the memory deallocation phase at program's end. My initial code introduces an OpenCV Mat i.e. Mat A without initialize it which creates the error. I fixed this error by using initialization i.e. A = Mat::zeros(...)

I want to confirm my previous doubt. If it is true, it is quite inconvenient to have to initialize Mat every time it is declared

Sorry for my bad explanation! please respond to me if I am not clear enough

Comment: I forget to mention that the Mat variable is declared in a class and the class destructor creates the memory error

Comment: Show us a minimal case please

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the deallocation happening at the end of my
>   program is proper. Is that correct?

`cv::Mat` allocates memory by itself and release it when all `cv::Mat` that shares the same data go out of scope (something similar to `std::shared_ptr`).

> I want to confirm my previous doubt. If it is true, it is quite
>   inconvenient to have to initialize Mat every time it is declared

No it is wrong. However, since you did not show a code I can just make a guess that you are not linking OpenCV yo your project correctly because it is famous case that a non well linked OpenCV causes errors at `cv::Mat` destruction stage.

Comment: sorry I tried but cannot replicate the error in a small project! btw, could you please explain a bit further about the linking error of OpenCV? but my program does not have that error all the time but only in one case

Comment: I do not have much information. However, When you mix 32-64 or release-debug binaries while linking to OpenCV this problem may occur. So, double check all the dlls and libs

Comment: the problem is fixed (in cmd line run) if I use initialization i.e. A = Mat::zeros(...). However, if I trace code using debug, it still appears

Comment: No it did not fixed. it has been hidden. if you are sure that you are not doing any thing wrong, sjut make sure that OpenCV is linked perfectly with all needed configuration and should be solved. Or put the code you are using so we can make sure that nothing is incorrect in it

Comment: I'll try again to compile a smaller code and upload